# how to delete duplicate in an array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, duplicates

I need to delete duplicate elements in an array.

This is my code:

```
struct client{
int index;
string name;
string surname;
string city;
int year;
float sell;};

client * elimina(client array[], int &n){
int j=0;
int i;
int a=0;
int trovato=0;
client *vet;
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    vet=new client[a+1];
    for(j=0;j<a;j++){
        if(array[i].index==vet[j].index){
            trovato=1;

            break;}}

    if(trovato==0){
        vet[a]=array[i];
        a++;}
    trovato=0;}
    n=a;
    return vet;
}
```

the code works but the output on the screen of the array is

```
    11-12181452000000000000000000000000000000010334500
```

Comment: `delete` seems a very poor choice for a function name. Is that really your code?

Comment: You can't really "delete" elements from an array. All you can do is change their value.

Comment: no it has a different name

Comment: You have a spectacular memory leak. Every time through the outer loop you do `vet=new client[a+1];` which allocates a __completely new array__. You only return the last one allocated and all the rest are leaked. Also note that none of the previous values are carried over into each new array so you are looking at junk values. This code doesn't look salvageable. Your task would be much simple if you used standard library containers and algorithms.

Comment: @AlessandroBossi Show real code please: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i've just edited the code

Comment: @juanchopanza is right, deleting from an array does not seem to be meaningful. Without huge time complexity and lots of work you can just mark the items that you want to delete as deleted/invalid. You can use a predetermined value for this task, which should not be confused with valid values. Moreover, you can copy the array items to a new array omitting the ones you want to remove, or remove an item from the original array and then shift all the remaining ones to the left (again this has a very big complexity). However, your code seems to be prune to leaks and I think should be simplified.

Comment: I'd say the easiest solution for the problem would be just using a [`std::vector<client>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of a `client array[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is very efficient.  You should sort your
array, then the duplicates will be adjacent and it's much
faster to remove them.

Use the relevant C++ standard data structures and functions.  First, you define a sorting
criterion for your clients:

```
bool operator<(client const& c1, client const& c2)
{ return c1.index < c2.index; }
```

Your function then becomes a lot simpler:

```
std::vector<client> elimina(std::vector<client> v) {
    // Sort on index so that std::unique can find all duplicates
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    // Shift duplicates
    auto const last = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end());
    // Resize the vector so duplicates drop out
    v.resize(last - v.begin());
    return v;
}
```

You need to include the 'vector' and 'algorithm' headers.

Notice the use of auto which only works for the 2011 version of C++ (C++11).
In earlier versions, it would be std::vector::iterator.

See the standard reference at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique 
for details.